# "Index out of range" with Firebase and populating cell

Tags: arrays, uitableview, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to post a dictionary to firebase that has the username as the key and the text as the value. I'm posting it like this:

```
 let dict = ["\(currentUser!)":"\(text)"]
Database.database().reference().child("posts/\(ourID!)/comment").setValue(dict)
```

What I'm trying to do her his populate a tableview with .subtitle cells populate it using the posts' text and user values so that way you can see the user's username and their post. **Note:** the problem is when I try to add a comment. This populates the tableview fine by itself when I'm reading the data. The problem is when I click a button to add another comment. For some reason I can't get the array to populate with the second post. The reason I have two arrays is because on is for the users, and one is for the text. Consequently, in the table view, each cell is populated with the corresponding post and matching user.

Here is how I'm reading the post(s):

```
let myTopPostsQuery = (Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("\(ourID!)/comment")).queryOrdered(byChild: "comment")

        myTopPostsQuery.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot)
            print("User: \(snapshot.key)")
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.comments.append(item)
                print("Comments so far: \(self.comments)")
            }
            if let item2 = snapshot.key as? String {
                self.keyUsers.append(item2)
                print("Our users \(self.keyUsers)")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
 tableView.reloadData()
```

The post is going to the Firebase Database successfully although I'm getting an error reading the username when I try to populate the tableview cell. I don't know why keyUsers won't work properly.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = keyUsers[indexPath.row]**Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your row count in numberOfRowsInSection for your tableView?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return keyUsers.count  //keyUsers should always be updated whenever there is changes in your items
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I still can't get the dictionary to post as an array. It just keeps rewriting the previous value.